# How to install pinax symposion sample project?

Tags: django, pinax

I am trying to learn Django and for this I would like to study a sample project to see how different apps on one homepage interact.

I was running into the [Pinax Symposion](https://github.com/pinax/symposion) sample which I cloned from GitHub and and tried to install it using

```
./setup.py build
./setup.py install
```

As I am new to Python and Django I do not know how to get the symposion sample up and running from there.

Do I need to add this application to the `settings.py`? How do I setup the urls?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shuold read the installation doc:
http://pinaxproject.com/docs/dev/gettingstarted/#installation

One you installed the virtual env and installed pinax, you have to run:

```
(mysite-env)$ python manage.py syncdb
(mysite-env)$ python manage.py runserver
```

Comment: OK I can just use `pip install`. I was getting the code via GitHub and did not know where to get from there. Thanks for your help.

Comment: but how do I get symposion running?

Comment: Check out the readme [here](https://github.com/eldarion/pycon). That's the same project

Comment: I checked out https://github.com/pinax/pinax-symposion-project but it does not work, as pinax-analytics is missing. the pycon template seems to be better documented. Fixture loading is not documented in the base pinax-symposion-project.